# So I was wondering why it truns out to be a false about my junit test

Tags: java, junit

here is my solution

```
public int count_chars_in_String(String s, String s1){
    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<s1.length(); j++){  
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j)){
                count += 1;

            }

        }
    }
```

and here is my rest code

```
@Test public void tests4(){
    code.Solution s =  new code.Solution();
    String input = "hhhhhey ";
    String input1 = "hhh";
    int expected = 3;
    int actual = s.count_chars_in_String(input, input1);
    assertTrue("Expected was" +expected+"but the actual was" +actual  ,  expected == actual);

}
```

every time i run the junit test it shows up that Expected was3 but actual was 15? How???I am so confusing.

Comment: Are you trying to get matches for the same corresponding position in both strings, or for anywhere in the other string?

Comment: I am trying to matche the same corresponding char in both string, dont have to be corresponding position

Answer (score 1):

Code which would give you result 3 would look probably like (note the `break` statement):

```
   // the outer loop
   for(int j = 0; j<s1.length(); j++){  
       // the inner loop
       for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
           if(s.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j)){
               count += 1;
               // Break the inner loop after finding
               // the match.
               break;
           }

       }
   }
```

Without the `break`, for each `h` in `hhh` (the outer loop), you increase the counter 5 times (the inner loop; because `h` occurs 5 times in `hhhhhey`).

Comment: so the break will break the outer loop or inner loop?

Comment: It is true that since add a break at the inner loop , so after count+=1 it will jump back to the outer loop start over again instead of jump back to inner loop to mutilpy h 5 times?

Comment: Yeah, it'd break the inner loop. So when first `h` from `hhh` (in the outer loop) equals to first `h` from `hhhhhey ` (the inner loop), the break will move the execution to the second `h` from the `hhh`, so from the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

do not know if this answer is what you are looking for and excuse my poor English.

The *for j* will run 3 times and for each of the times the *for i* will run 5 times, that are equal to the time that the condition is met. Now 5x3=15, the result that you get.

if what you expect is to get the number characters that match each string (3), then just do the following:

```js
for(int i = 0; i<s1.length();i++){
    if(s.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(i)){
        count += 1;

    }

 }
```

Regards.

Comment: I have try that already It doesnt work unless u declear a j like the code I post. I will work when I add a break statement. Like the 2th answer I got. thank u anyway